# Why does read's timeout break my console?

Tags: bash, terminal, less

I have a script that is causing an issue, I've boiled it down to this;

```sh
#/bin/bash
read -t 1 -p 'Wanna continue?'
less +F readTimeout.sh
echo 'Wont get printed'
```

The original script operated by prompting the user to continue, but after waiting for five seconds (in this case, one) it will continue on its own.
It then proceeds to tail from a log file (in this case, itself, for demonstrative purposes).
Then it should execute the rest of the commands after the user closes `less`.

Well, when `less` is in `tail` mode, you need to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop it from following the file (then you can scroll/search on what's in `less` so far, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to follow again, or <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit).

The problem for this script is, when you `^C` it kills `less`, takes you back to prompt (i.e. the rest of the commands aren't ran) and stops anything you type from being echoed (if you hit enter your commands are actually being written to the console, though)!

Without the `-t` switch on `read` (or if you respond before the timeout) it works fine.
Any ideas why this happens &/or how to combat this? So far I've resorted to just forcing the user to respond to the prompt (i.e. removing the `timeout` flag from `read`)

P.S.
This is terminal emulator independent (tested `konsole` and `xterm`).
And I've tried placing `stty sane` after the `read` line in case it would fix it.

Comment: The script works fine for me. Can you provide more details about your system?

Comment: CentOS 6.4, what would you like to know?